# Get and set methods which depends on other field

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I don't know how to phrase this in title. What is Kotlin equivalent of Java code here. All my tries ended up with error or stackoverflow. This is happening when serializing with Jackson.

```
public class Test {
    private String test1;
    private String test2;

    public String getTest1() {
        return test1;
    }

    public void setTest1(String test1) {
        this.test1 = test1;
    }

    public String getTest2() {
        return test2!=null? test2:test1;
    }

    public void setTest2(String test2) {
        this.test2 = test2;
    }
}
```

Kotlin code below,

```
class Test(var test1: String? = "") {
    var test2: String?
        get() = if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(test2)) test2 else test1
        set(test2Val) {
            test2 = test2Val
        }
}
```

What Kotlin fundamentals I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test2` would end up calling the getter. You can look at the resulting Java code for reference.

In custom getters and setters, you use `field` instead. So the correct code would be:

```
class Test(var test1: String? = "") {
    var test2: String?
        get() = if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(field)) field else test1
        set(test2Val) {
            field = test2Val
        }
}
```

**Note:** this causes a second problem. You haven't initialized the variable, which you have to do with vars. If you have a `val` and a custom getter that returns something else (i.e. `val x = ... get() = someOtherVar`, that doesn't give a compiler error). This does not apply to `var`s though. However, in your case, using `= null` (or alternatively `= ""`) should be enough.

But since you said you get StackOverflowErrors and not an error related to a lack of initialization, I'm guessing you actually do initialize it, but just didn't include it in the MCVE. But if you didn't, that's worth noting.

---

Also, Kotlin has methods like `isNotEmpty()` and `isNotBlank()` which replace the need for `StringUtils.isNotEmpty()`, and is called like `field.isNotEmpty()`. Note that here you want to do `if(field?.isNotEmpty() == true) ...`, because you end up with a nullable boolean. It also means it returns test1 if field is null, or empty. You can also add `isNotBlank` if you feel like it.

And you don't need to declare setters manually if they do exactly the same as a generated one. An IDE like IntelliJ will also warn you if you do this, and suggest you remove it. It doesn't really matter if you declare it manually or not if it's the default setter, but it helps you write some less code.

Comment: I missed this part in docs, 'This backing field can be referenced in the accessors using the field identifier' . Is there any reason for doing this in Kotlin? Is there equivalent of this in other languages?

Comment: Kotlin works differently than other languages though. In Java, you have fields directly, and do stuff with them; getters, setters, etc. Kotlin actually uses properties(/variables), not fields. Fields can be accessed using the `field` keyword, as you mentioned, but the key here is the system. I assume there are other programming languages that do the same, but Java doesn't. It's mostly about the design of the language features, so it's not like a method in the stdlib of a language.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test(var test1: String? = "") {
    var test2: String?
        get() = if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(test2)) test2 else test1
        set(test2Val) {
            test2 = test2Val // here you are recursively setting the value of test2              
        }
}
```

If you want to assign the value to the [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields), it should be

```
field = test2Val
```

In this case though, the setter would be pointless because if you don't declare it, it would have the same behavior. 
The idea is that `field` is the private property, and `get` and `set` are the setter. You can than choose what to return from the getter, and what to do with the value passed to the setter.

The other problem is that `test2` needs an initial value, in Java it would be initialized by default to `null` but in Kotlin you have to explicitly assign an initial value. So for instance with an empty string:

```
class Test(var test1: String? = "") {
    var test2: String? = ""
        get() = if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(test2)) test2 else test1
}
```